# cqwp: querying a whole site looking for documents, I get also css files and png

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

I am doing a simple CQWP in a site where I would like to query all documents. I have selected 'show items from the following site and subsites' and show items from 'document library', 'document content type' and 'document'.

My results (from a test site that is empty except 5 word documents, show those 5 documents + some css files and some png files.

Why it is giving me css and png, after selecting documents all the way?

How do I filter out documents only?

Comment: Where are your css, png files stored?

Comment: in /Style%20Library/Images and Style%20Library/forms. Why they come up if I told I wanted just documents?

Comment: because style library is also a document library : template id - 101.

Comment: I had also set to search for documents, css and png are documents? shouldn't png fall under the image content type?

Comment: Style Library content type is Document hence you see css and png files in your results. If you move the image file to the Image library and upload it as an Image content type then you will not see this png file in your cqwp results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Style Library` is also a document library technically with a `template ID 101`.

[image]

You can try following query in your `query override` for example to get only `.docx` or `.pdf` files

```
<Where>
<Or>
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
<Value Type='Text'>.docx</Value>
</Contains>
<Contains>
<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />
<Value Type='Text'>.pdf</Value>
</Contains>
</Or>
</Where>
```

**OR** 
You can filter your results through the UI as below:
[image]